# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando ejecutar una tarea programada cron. Me devuelve el error: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file (ruta al archivo) on line 200. ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

```
 <?php

__autoload('usuarios');

class html_usuarios extends usuarios{


       public function print_routing($accion,$idRegistroUsuario=FALSE){
         $html = "";

           $arrDatosRegistroUsuario = array();

             if($idRegistroUsuario) $arrDatosRegistroUsuario = 
             $this->getUsuario($idRegistroUsuario);


               ob_start();


         if($accion=='editar'){?>
          <?="Usuarios >" ." Edición > 
   ".$arrDatosRegistroUsuario['nombre'];?>
    <?}elseif($accion=='alta'){?>
        <?="Usuarios >" ." Alta ";?>
    <?}else{?>
        <?="Usuarios >" .$arrDatosRegistroUsuario['nombre'];?>
    <?}?>


    <?
    $html = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;

}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
*
*/
public function print_formulario_alta($insertado=0){

    global $arrIdiomas;

    $html = "";
    ob_start();



    if($insertado>0){?>
        <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.
   </div>
    <?}else{?>
        <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>
    <?}?>

    <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server" class="ocultar"></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" 
    id="id_registro_grabado">

    <label <?=(in_array('nombre',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' 
    class="requerido" ':'')?>>Nombre</label><input type="text" name="nombre" 
    id="nombre" value="">
    <label <?=(in_array('apellidos',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' 
       class="requerido" ':'')?>>Apellidos</label><input type="text" 
 name="apellidos" id="apellidos" value="">

    <label <?=(in_array('email',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Email Notificaciones</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" onblur="this.form.usuario.value=quitartodosBlancos(this.value);">
    <label <?=(in_array('usuario',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Usuario</label><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" value="" readonly="readonly">
    <label <?=(in_array('password',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
    <label <?=(in_array('password',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Repetir Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="repassword" id="repassword" value="">
    <input name="btnpass" type="button" class="button grande green" class="boton" id="btnpass" onClick="passGenerator(this.form)" value="Generar Password" >

    <label>Super Administrador</label><br><input type="checkbox" class="pequeno" name="superadmin" id="superadmin" value="1"></label>

    <br /> <br />
    <?if($insertado==0){?>
        <input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">
            <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
        <?}else{?>
            <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
    <?}?>

    </form>

    <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">

    <?
    $html = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;

}

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
*
*/
public function print_formulario_editar($id,$insertado=0){

    global $arrIdiomas;
    $html = "";

    $arrDatosRegistro = $this->getUsuario($id);

    ob_start();




    if($insertado>0){?>
        <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.</div>
    <?}else{?>
        <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>
    <?}?>
    <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server"  class="ocultar"></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$id;?>" name="id_registro" id="id_registro">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" id="id_registro_grabado">

    <label <?=(in_array('nombre',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Nombre</label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?=mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['nombre']);?>">
    <label <?=(in_array('apellidos',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Apellidos</label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" value="<?=mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['apellidos']);?>">



    <label <?=(in_array('email',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Email Notificaciones</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['email']);?>">


    <label>Super Administrador</label><br><input type="checkbox" class="pequeno" name="superadmin" id="superadmin" value="1" <?=(($arrDatosRegistro['superadmin']==1)? ' checked ': '')?>></label>




    <br /><br />
    <?if($insertado==0){?>
    <input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">
    <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
    <?}?>
    </form>
    <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">

    <?
    $html = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;

}


 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
*
*/
public function print_formulario_editar_password($id,$insertado=0){

    global $arrIdiomas;
    $html = "";

    $arrDatosRegistro = $this->getUsuario($id);

    ob_start();


    if($insertado>0){?>
        <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.</div>
    <?}else{?>
        <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>
    <?}?>
    <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server"  class="ocultar"></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$id;?>" name="id_registro" id="id_registro">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" id="id_registro_grabado">



    <label <?=(in_array('password',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
    <label <?=(in_array('password',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Repetir Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="repassword" id="repassword" value="">
    <input name="btnpass" type="button" class="button grande green" class="boton" id="btnpass" onClick="passGenerator(this.form)" value="Generar Password" >





    <br /><br />
    <?if($insertado==0){?>
    <input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">
    <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
    <?}?>
    </form>
    <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">

      <?
    $html = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;

     }
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: ¿Sigue sin estar resuelta esta pregunta? Por favor, actualiza la pregunta con los avances que hayas hecho (si los hay) y envía un comentario actualizando el estado del problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Debido a que no has hecho un uso adecuado de la indentación del código en PHP, no te has percatado que te faltaba la apertura de unas llaves en el primer `if` y la llave al final para cerrar la declaración de la clase:

```
<?php
__autoload('usuarios');

class html_usuarios extends usuarios {
    public function print_routing($accion, $idRegistroUsuario = false)
    {
        $html = "";
        $arrDatosRegistroUsuario = array();

        // Aquí agregué una llave al final del *if*
        if ($idRegistroUsuario) {
            $arrDatosRegistroUsuario = $this->getUsuario($idRegistroUsuario);
            ob_start();
            if ($accion == 'editar') {
                echo "Usuarios > Edición > ". htmlspecialchars($arrDatosRegistroUsuario['nombre']);
            } elseif ($accion == 'alta') {
                echo "Usuarios > Alta ";
            } else {
                echo "Usuarios > " . htmlspecialchars($arrDatosRegistroUsuario['nombre']);
            }
            $html = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $html;
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*
    *
    */
    public function print_formulario_alta($insertado = 0)
    {
        global $arrIdiomas;

        $html = "";
        ob_start();

        if ($insertado > 0) {
            echo '<div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>';
        }
        ?>
        <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server" class="ocultar"></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" 
        id="id_registro_grabado">

        <label <?= (in_array('nombre', $this->obtener_campos_requeridos()) ? 'class="requerido" ':'') ?> />
            Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="">
        <label <?= (in_array('apellidos',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'') ?> />
            Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" value="" />
        <label <?= (in_array('email', $this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Email Notificaciones</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" onblur="this.form.usuario.value=quitartodosBlancos(this.value);">
        <label <?= (in_array('usuario', $this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'') ?>/>
            Usuario</label><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" value="" readonly="readonly">
        <label <?= (in_array('password', $this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'') ?>/>
            Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
        <label <?= (in_array('password', $this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'') ?>/>
            Repetir Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="repassword" id="repassword" value="">
        <input name="btnpass" type="button" class="button grande green" class="boton" id="btnpass" onClick="passGenerator(this.form)" value="Generar Password" />
        <label>Super Administrador</label><br><input type="checkbox" class="pequeno" name="superadmin" id="superadmin" value="1"></label>
        <br /><br />
        <?php
        if ($insertado == 0) {
            echo '<input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">';
        }
        ?>
        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location = '/g-usuarios.php'">
        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location = '/g-usuarios.php'">
        </form>
        <?php
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $html;
    }

     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*
    *
    */
    public function print_formulario_editar($id, $insertado = 0)
    {
        global $arrIdiomas;
        $html = "";
        $arrDatosRegistro = $this->getUsuario($id);
        ob_start();
        if ($insertado > 0) {
            echo'<div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>';
        }
        ?>
        <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server"  class="ocultar"></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$id;?>" name="id_registro" id="id_registro">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" id="id_registro_grabado">
        <label <?= (in_array('nombre',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'') ?> />
            Nombre</label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?= mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['nombre']) ?>">
        <label <?= (in_array('apellidos',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'') ?> />
            Apellidos</label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" value="<?= mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['apellidos']) ?>">
        <label <?= (in_array('email',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'') ?> />
            Email Notificaciones</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?= mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['email']) ?>">
        <label>Super Administrador</label><br><input type="checkbox" class="pequeno" name="superadmin"
            id="superadmin" value="1" <?= ($arrDatosRegistro['superadmin'] == 1)?'checked':'' ?>></label>
        <br /><br />
        <?php
        if ($insertado == 0) {
            ?>
            <input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">
            <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </form>
        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
        <?php
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $html;
    }

     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*
    *
    */
    public function print_formulario_editar_password($id, $insertado = 0)
    {
        global $arrIdiomas;
        $html = "";
        $arrDatosRegistro = $this->getUsuario($id);
        ob_start();
        if ($insertado > 0) {
            echo '<div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>';
        }
        ?>
        <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server"  class="ocultar"></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?= $id ?>" name="id_registro" id="id_registro">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" id="id_registro_grabado">
        <label <?= (in_array('password', $this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'')?> />
            Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
        <label <?= (in_array('password', $this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?'class="requerido"':'')?> />
            Repetir Contraseña</label>
        <input type="text" name="repassword" id="repassword" value="">
        <input name="btnpass" type="button" class="button grande green" class="boton" id="btnpass" onClick="passGenerator(this.form)" value="Generar Password" >
        <br /><br />
        <?php
        if ($insertado == 0) {
            ?>
            <input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">
            <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </form>
        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
        <?php
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $html;
    }
// Aquí olvidaste la llave de cierre de la clase
}
```

Te recomiendo que te pases por las [recomendaciones PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) para que leas acerca de las mejores prácticas que puedes usar para facilitar la lectura de tu código y su depuración.

Answer (score 0):

ese error significa que tienes una condicion que no has cerrado o nested..

- agregue un `}` en la linea 36 ( para cerrar el metodo print_formulario_editar_password)
- elemine el ultimo } que tenias

-
ejecuta el codigo.. y dime si aparece algun error

```
 <?php

    __autoload('usuarios');

    class html_usuarios extends usuarios{


           public function print_routing($accion,$idRegistroUsuario=FALSE){
             $html = "";

               $arrDatosRegistroUsuario = array();

                 if($idRegistroUsuario) $arrDatosRegistroUsuario = 
                 $this->getUsuario($idRegistroUsuario);


                   ob_start();


             if($accion=='editar'){?>
              <?="Usuarios >" ." Edición > 
       ".$arrDatosRegistroUsuario['nombre'];?>
        <?}elseif($accion=='alta'){?>
            <?="Usuarios >" ." Alta ";?>
        <?}else{?>
            <?="Usuarios >" .$arrDatosRegistroUsuario['nombre'];?>
        <?}?>


        <?
        $html = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();
        return $html;

    }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*
    *
    */
    public function print_formulario_alta($insertado=0){

        global $arrIdiomas;

        $html = "";
        ob_start();



        if($insertado>0){?>
            <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.
       </div>
        <?}else{?>
            <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>
        <?}?>

        <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server" class="ocultar"></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" 
        id="id_registro_grabado">

        <label <?=(in_array('nombre',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' 
        class="requerido" ':'')?>>Nombre</label><input type="text" name="nombre" 
        id="nombre" value="">
        <label <?=(in_array('apellidos',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' 
           class="requerido" ':'')?>>Apellidos</label><input type="text" 
     name="apellidos" id="apellidos" value="">

        <label <?=(in_array('email',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Email Notificaciones</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" onblur="this.form.usuario.value=quitartodosBlancos(this.value);">
        <label <?=(in_array('usuario',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Usuario</label><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" value="" readonly="readonly">
        <label <?=(in_array('password',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
        <label <?=(in_array('password',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Repetir Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="repassword" id="repassword" value="">
        <input name="btnpass" type="button" class="button grande green" class="boton" id="btnpass" onClick="passGenerator(this.form)" value="Generar Password" >

        <label>Super Administrador</label><br><input type="checkbox" class="pequeno" name="superadmin" id="superadmin" value="1"></label>

        <br /> <br />
        <?if($insertado==0){?>
            <input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">
                <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
            <?}else{?>
                <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
        <?}?>

        </form>

        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">

        <?
        $html = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();
        return $html;

    }

     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*
    *
    */
    public function print_formulario_editar($id,$insertado=0){

        global $arrIdiomas;
        $html = "";

        $arrDatosRegistro = $this->getUsuario($id);

        ob_start();




        if($insertado>0){?>
            <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.</div>
        <?}else{?>
            <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>
        <?}?>
        <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server"  class="ocultar"></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$id;?>" name="id_registro" id="id_registro">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" id="id_registro_grabado">

        <label <?=(in_array('nombre',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Nombre</label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?=mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['nombre']);?>">
        <label <?=(in_array('apellidos',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Apellidos</label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" value="<?=mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['apellidos']);?>">



        <label <?=(in_array('email',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Email Notificaciones</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=mostrar_html($arrDatosRegistro['email']);?>">


        <label>Super Administrador</label><br><input type="checkbox" class="pequeno" name="superadmin" id="superadmin" value="1" <?=(($arrDatosRegistro['superadmin']==1)? ' checked ': '')?>></label>




        <br /><br />
        <?if($insertado==0){?>
        <input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">
        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
        <?}?>
        </form>
        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">

        <?
        $html = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();
        return $html;

    }


     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*
    *
    */
    public function print_formulario_editar_password($id,$insertado=0){

        global $arrIdiomas;
        $html = "";

        $arrDatosRegistro = $this->getUsuario($id);

        ob_start();


        if($insertado>0){?>
            <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server">Elemento guardado correctamente.</div>
        <?}else{?>
            <div id="div_mensajes_ok_server" class="ocultar"></div>
        <?}?>
        <form action="" id="frm_ficha" name="frm_ficha" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="div_mensajes_ko_server"  class="ocultar"></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$id;?>" name="id_registro" id="id_registro">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_registro_grabado" id="id_registro_grabado">



        <label <?=(in_array('password',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
        <label <?=(in_array('password',$this->obtener_campos_requeridos())?' class="requerido" ':'')?>>Repetir Contraseña</label><input type="text" name="repassword" id="repassword" value="">
        <input name="btnpass" type="button" class="button grande green" class="boton" id="btnpass" onClick="passGenerator(this.form)" value="Generar Password" >





        <br /><br />
        <?if($insertado==0){?>
        <input type="submit"  value="Aceptar" class="button medium green" id="guardar" name="guardar">
        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Cancelar" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">
        <?}?>
        </form>
        <input id="cancelar" name="cancelar" type="button" class="button medium gris" value="Volver" onclick="document.location='/g-usuarios.php'">

          <?
        $html = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();
        return $html;

         }

         ?>
```

Comment: Sigue dando el mismo error. Además la clase class html_usuarios extends usuarios tiene que englobar el resto de funciones, no?

Comment: de hecho si tienes toda la razon...oops no me fije que era una class..tienes que englobar todo el testo del codigo como dices

Comment: @JosicoLol sigues teniendo el mismo error?